# tkk Notebook doesn't display after placing it inside a class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to add a tkk notebook to an existing program of mine, but having some issues. To troubleshoot, I followed an online tutorial, and created a tkk notebook with two tabs in a barebones program:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(pady=10, expand=True)

frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=400, height=280)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=400, height=280)

frame1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
frame2.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

notebook.add(frame1, text='General Information')
notebook.add(frame2, text='Profile')

root.mainloop()
```

This worked fine, so I took it one step towards my original program by replacing the top three lines with

```
class Notebook_Test(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.geometry('400x300')

        notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
```

and the bottom one with

```
frame01 = Notebook_Test()
frame01.tk.mainloop()
```

properly indenting everything else, of course. To my surprise, these minor changes *already* broke it, and the window that displays is completely empty. I'm probably missing something fundamental, as I couldn't find any questions on this topic, but I'm not sure what it is that I should be looking for, so if someone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `pack` or `grid` on `notebook` to make sure it is visible inside it's container. You also need to call `pack` or `grid` on `frame01` to make that available inside the root window.

Comment: I didn't remove the `notebook.pack` that was in the original code. As for `pack`ing `frame01`, that... seems to work? I've never had to do that before, as everything displayed perfectly fine before I added the notebook to my original program, without packing frame01. Unfortunately, when porting the `.pack` back to my original program, there is still an error, but that program is _far_ longer than this, so I'm not sure how I'd condense it for a question here.

Comment: @Darkstar: _"I didn't remove the notebook.pack that was in the original code. "_ - I don't know what you mean by that. The class definition you gave in your question does not include a call to `notebook.pack()`. _something_ has to call `notebook.pack()`, and it would be very strange to do that outside of the class so I assumed you simply forgot to add it in the class.

Comment: The class was identical to the original in the middle, so I only showed the parts that were different. The top three lines and last line were replaced, but everything else (such as `notebook.pack(pady=10, expand=True)` on line 4) was untouched.